# How to use awk to parse values from stdout as elements of an array?

Tags: bash, awk

The command `elb-describe-instance-health` returns the following

```
INSTANCE_ID  i-111
INSTANCE_ID  i-222
INSTANCE_ID  i-333
```

`$(elb-describe-instance-health | awk '/INSTANCE_ID/{print $2}')`

returns `i-111 i-222 i-3333`

How can I change the above syntax to store each of these values in an array (ex. `foo[0]` equals `i-111`, `foo[1]` equals `i-222`, `foo[2]` equals `i-333`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
array=($(elb-describe-instance-health | awk '/INSTANCE_ID/ { print $2 }'))
```

Then simply `echo` the element you want. To `echo` the first element for example, try:

```
echo "${array[0]}"
```

Comment: I assumed your looking to store the elements you want in a shell array. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: IFS needs to be reset if this is not used in a script :p

Comment: Setting `IFS` is only necessary if you *only* want to word-split on newlines. The default value is sufficient for the example given.

Comment: @Steve That is a brilliant and elegant solution, much better than the tired old (and dangerous!) "eval $(awk '...')" I was going to suggest. Can't believe I haven't come across that before. Thanks!

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I tend to avoid `eval`. Sometimes it's safe ... you know the story :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(elb-describe-instance-health |awk '/INSTANCE_ID/ { foo[i++] = $2 }')
```

but I guess you would like to do something with foo.